# How to configure core dumps (`ulimit -c`) from within sudo within docker

Tags: linux, docker, sudo

I am having an issue with missing core dumps within docker containers. I have found the root cause of this is `sudo` resetting the `ulimit -c` value:

```
/$ ulimit -c 80
/$ ulimit -c
80
/$ sudo sh -c 'ulimit -c'
0
/$ sudo sh -c 'ulimit -c 70'
sh: 1: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
```

Here I set the ulimit in the outer shell which works. When I enter a `sudo` shell, the ulimit is ignored *and* I cannot set it again to some other value.

I have found the EPERM is from the soft limit being above the hard limit, but I also cannot change the hard limit.

One other thing I tried was configuring the limits.conf. I did this within the dockerfile to ensure it took effect:

```
RUN bash -c "echo 'root soft core 100' |sudo tee /etc/security/limits.conf"
RUN bash -c "echo 'session required pam_limits.so' |sudo tee -a /etc/pam.d/common-session"
```

However, this had no effect either.

Adding `--privileged` to `docker run` does work, but I would prefer to not do that.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of `sudo` by default reset the core size limit to zero. To keep the previous values add to config this statement:

```
Defaults rlimit_core=default
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the issue is the permissions, though:
/$ sudo sh -c 'ulimit -c 70'
sh: 1: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

 tried setting the rlimit_core config like you suggested, but the sudo debug log show the same permission denial: `setrlimit(rlimit_core, [5, 5]): Operation not permitted @ set_policy_rlimits() ../../src/limits.c:639` (note: i set it to 5 in this case for ease of debugging). So it ends up getting dropped anyways

Comment: Can you paste the content of your /etc/security/limits.conf file?

Comment: which version of _sudo_ did add that feature? Debian  bullseye contains 1.9.5p2-3+deb11u1 , and _rlimit_core_ cannot be used.. That's weird, since according to documentation, it should be present in >= 1.8.7

Comment: SUDO_1_9_5 tag's date is "Jan 9 13:12:30 2021 -0700" and commit "Add basic support for setting resource limits in sudoers" is dated "Nov 8 17:46:19 2021 -0700" so there's a risk this is not included.